# Unexpected encoding or content of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 2.0.0 message

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 2.0.0** to subscribe for queue messages, and get unexpected characters when I use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(serviceBusMessage.Body)`.

[image]

It looks like the message content should have been valid XML, but its certainly not.

The code that sends messages, uses the old **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 4.1.6** library, and looks like this:

`private void SendToProcessingQueue(Guid accountId, Message msg)
{
    string queueName = msg.MessageType.ToLower();
    var client = CreateQueueClient(queueName);
    client.Send(new BrokeredMessage(new MessageHint()
    {
        AccountId = accountId,
        MessageId = msg.Id,
        MessageType = msg.MessageType
    }));
}`

Are the new and old libraries incompatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create compatible messages it seems you need to encode them using a `DataContractBinarySerializer`. Thankfully they include one in the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` nuget package. The compatibility serialization function looks like this:

```
byte[] Serialize<T>(T input)
{
    var serializer = Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.InteropExtensions.DataContractBinarySerializer<T>.Instance;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(256);
    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, input);
    memoryStream.Flush();
    memoryStream.Position = 0L;
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

So sending your message with the new library would look like:

```
private void SendToProcessingQueue(Guid accountId, Message msg)
{
    string queueName = msg.MessageType.ToLower();
    var client = CreateQueueClient(queueName);
    client.Send(new Message(Serialize(new MessageHint()
    {
        AccountId = accountId,
        MessageId = msg.Id,
        MessageType = msg.MessageType
    })));
}
```

If you are receiving a message with the new library from the old library, the developers of the new library have helpfully provided an extension method `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.InteropExtensions.MessageInteropExtensions.GetBody<T>` to read the message in a compatible way. You use it like this:

```
MessageHint hint = message.GetBody<MessageHint>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible or not - I was able to parse the message after reimplementing the class library as .NET 4.7 instead of .NET Standard 2.0 and referencing **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 4.1.7** instead of **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 2.0.0**. The API is about the same, so it took me only 15 minutes to reimplement.

[image]

**Update:** If someone knows how to exchange messages between the two versions, please post another answer describing how it should be done.